# what is the equivalent of PRINTER_INFO_2 struct in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

what is the equivalent of PRINTER_INFO_2 struct of c++ in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pinvoke.net is your friend](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/PRINTER_INFO_2.html):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct PRINTER_INFO_2
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pServerName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pPrinterName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pShareName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pPortName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pDriverName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pComment;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pLocation;
    public IntPtr pDevMode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pSepFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pPrintProcessor;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pDatatype;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pParameters;
    public IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor;
    public uint Attributes;
    public uint Priority;
    public uint DefaultPriority;
    public uint StartTime;
    public uint UntilTime;
    public uint Status;
    public uint cJobs;
    public uint AveragePPM;
}
```

Comment: did not know about pinvoke.net yet - that's neat!